# Electromagnetism - Why electric and magnetic fields are manifestations of the same phenomenon

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, maxwell-equations

Maxwell's equations reveal an interdependency between electric and magnetic fields, inasmuch as a time varying magnetic field generates a rotating electric field and vice versa. Furthermore, the equations predict that even in the absence of any sources one can have self propagating electric and magnetic fields, so called electromagnetic waves.

However, is it correct to say that although Maxwell's equations show that electric and magnetic fields are interdependent, they do not imply that the two are different aspects of the same underlying physical phenomenon?!

Given this, is it then correct to say that it is not until one takes into account special relativity that it becomes clear that electricity and magnetism are different manifestations of the same underlying phenomenon?

Indeed, if one considers a frame of reference in which only an electric (or magnetic) field is observed, then, upon a Lorentz transformation to another frame of reference, it is found that one will observe a combination of electric and magnetic fields. This implies that the two are not independent of one another, since there is no observer independent manner in which one can separate electric and magnetic fields, hence implying that they are manifestations of the same underlying field - the electromagnetic field?!

---

**Edit**

In essence, my question is, can one deduce purely from Maxwell's equations that the electric and magnetic fields are actually "the same" field, or is this (necessary) unification not explicitly confirmed until one takes into account special relativity?

Comment: Special relativity is itself derived from the Maxwell equations, which predict a fixed propagation speed for the electromagnetic waves.

Comment: @OrangeDog Relativity is not *derived* from Maxwell's equations.

Comment: they are the same object ( and not manifestations of another object ) , the magnetic field being the electric field as seen in a moving frame

Comment: @lemon OK, is "directly follows from them" better? The Maxwell equations are the basis for the development of the theory of special relativity.

Comment: @OrangeDog Also not quite right. The invariance of light speed was taken as a *postulate* (even though it's true that Einstein *probably* got this idea from Maxwell's equations).

Comment: @igael         Yes, you're right, I was just trying to emphasise the fact that they are unified into a single object, but that historically they were thought of as two distinct objects. Is it correct though, to say that it is through application of special relativity that such a unification is explicitly shown, in the sense that there is no observer independent way to separate the two and as such they the same object?

Comment: @user35305 Yes they are just Lorentz transformations of each other.

Comment: not really, it was already the case with Maxwell equations, which are , on another hand compatible with special relativity rather than with classical mechanics

Comment: @lemon         Ok cool. So is what I wrote a correct understanding?

Comment: @igael         Maxwell's equations don't explicitly show that they are the same object though, they simply show that the two are interdependent, i.e. one can generate the other.

Comment: perhaps, but as today, the Maxwell synthesis is sufficient to identify them, letting to other theories deeper interpretations. Agreeing on the main ... ( surely, the difference comes from the objects : previously forces, now fields )

Comment: @igael         Would what I've written on the whole be a correct understanding, though?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here: Sure, if you *willfully ignore* one of the most important results of physics from the last century (i.e. relativity), then you might not be able to say that electric and magnetic fields really are "the same". What's your point?

Comment: @ACuriousMind  My question really is, is it true that one cannot definitively conclude that the electric and magnetic fields really are "the same" without appealing to special relativity?

Comment: I vote that the hold on this question be removed. The question has been edited and in my view it is now clear enough where the confusion lies so that one can provide an answer that would give the necessary explanations to address the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Electric and magnetic fields are field strengths of a gauge field. If you consider any matter field/particle Lagrangian, its coupling constant is the same for Electric and magnetic fields.

For eg. classically in the Lorentz force equation $\vec{F}=q(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B})$. Notice that $q$ is the parameter that gives the coupling of the particle with Electric as well as magnetic field.

This is what we mean when we say the two forces are unified.

Edit: Reply to whether historical approach is the one to use relativity

I have to disagree. Electric and magnetic field were realized to be the same once Maxwell wrote his equations and light was found out to be an electromagnetic wave by Hertz. It is true the Maxwell equations are Lorentz covariant and when you do that you have a single four potential that gives electric and magnetic fields. And then you add coupling with relativistic matter Lagrangians. Then it is natural to have a single coupling constant. So it was rather me who was taking the historical approach. Anyhow it is also modern. When you consider the standard model, weak interaction and electromagnetic interaction are given by the same $SU(2)_L$ field multiplet. But there are still two coupling constants which is why it is not a unification

Comment: From an historical perspective though (and also from a pedagogical approach), before introducing the notion of gauge fields and the like, is it correct to say that it is not one takes into account special relativity that it becomes abundantly clear that electricity and magnetism are aspects of the same field - the electromagnetic field, since there is no observer independent manner in which one can separate the two?!

Comment: I disagree. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. The issue I find is that, although Maxwell's equations predict "self reinforcing" propagating electromagnetic waves, it is really a statement that time varying electric fields and magnetic fields can generate one another such that they create an electromagnetic wave propagating through space. However, I don't see how one can conclude that they are the same object from this, it simply implies that they are interdependent...

Comment: ... Surely it only explicitly becomes evident that they are "the same" once one studies how they transform under Lorentz transformations, in which it is found that the two "rotate" into one another and hence are really "the same" object?!

Comment: I want to stress the point about coupling constants again because I believe the answer to this question should illustrate what is the general idea of unification

Comment: If you want to hear the coupling constant argument in words it is that a moving 'charge' produces both electric and magnetic fields which are intertwined. In fact in some gauge choice, both are given by the vector potential $\vec{A}$. But more crucially, they are both associated with the same coupling constant which is the charge

Comment: So is the point that the if one takes into account the form of the Lorentz force, it is evident that the coupling to the electric and magnetic fields is identical, implying that they are in fact "the same", a single entity. If they were distinct fields then they would have distinct coupling constants?! This, along with the fact that Maxwell's equations describe the dependence between electric and magnetic fields (as well as predicting the existence of electromagnetic waves), reveals the unification of electric and magnetic fields?!